# Extract the factor's values positions in level

Tags: r, r-factor

I'm returning to R after some time, and the following has me stumped:

I'd like to build a list of the positions factor values have in the facor levels list.
Example:

```
> data = c("a", "b", "a","a","c")
> fdata = factor(data)
> fdata
[1] a b a a c
Levels: a b c
> fdata$lvl_idx <- ????
```

Such that:

```
> fdata$lvl_idx
[1] 1 2 1 1 3
```

Appreciate any hints or tips.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution provided years ago by Matthew Lundberg is not robust. It could be that the `as.integer()` function was defined for a specific S3 type of factors. Imagine someone would create a new factor class to keep operators like `>=`.

```
as.myfactor <- function(x, ...) {
  structure(as.factor(x), class = c("myfactor", "factor"))
}

# and that someone would create an S3 method for integers - it should
# only remove the operators, which makes sense...
as.integer.myfactor <- function(x, ...) {
  as.integer(gsub("(<|=|>)+", "", as.character(x)))
}
```

Now this is not working anymore, - it just removes operators:

```
f <- as.myfactor(">=2")
as.integer(f)
#> [1] 2
```

But this *is* robust with any factor you want to know the index of the level of, using `which()`:

```
f <- factor(2:4)
which(levels(f) == 2)
#> [1] 1
```

Answer (score 13):

If you convert a factor to integer, you get the position in the levels:

```
as.integer(fdata)
## [1] 1 2 1 1 3
```

In certain situations, this is counter-intuitive:

```
f <- factor(2:4)
f
## [1] 2 3 4
## Levels: 2 3 4
as.integer(f)
## [1] 1 2 3
```

Also if you silently coerce to integer, for example by using a factor as a vector index:

```
LETTERS[2:4]
## [1] "B" "C" "D"
LETTERS[f]
## [1] "A" "B" "C"
```

Converting to `character` before converting to `integer` gives the expected values.  See `?factor` for details.